# How to change the range of cell in For … Each loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I built a `For … Each` loop that finds the string and adds a column to the left.

The problem is that I need to declare the range and I can't change it dynamically to the same range of the column of the string location.

Here is the code:

```vb
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim newcolumn As Range

    Set newcolumn = Range("A:A")
    Set myRange = Range("A1:cc1")

    For Each myCell In myRange
        If myCell = "size" Then
            newcolumn = myCell
            newcolumn.EntireColumn.Insert
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

How can I add the column the the left of the `myCell` range?

Comment: Try `myCell.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert`

Answer (score 0):

I think should do what you want:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim skip As Boolean

Set myRange = Range("A1:cc1")

skip = False

For Each myCell In myRange
    If myCell = "size" And Not skip Then
        myCell.EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight
        skip = True
    Else
        skip = False
    End If

Next myCell
```

The code iterates over all cells in `myRange` and when ever it finds a cell with `"size"` it adds a new column to the left of that cell.